# Problem with join query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is the query which works but with some errors:

```
SELECT dbo.Booking.Cost, 
       dbo.Booking.StatusID, 
       dbo.Account.FirstName, 
       dbo.Attendee.HelmetsPurchased AS ProductsPurchased, 
       dbo.Attendee.GaragesPurchased, 
       dbo.Attendee.SecondDriver AS [Driver Name]
  FROM dbo.Booking 
  JOIN dbo.Attendee ON dbo.Booking.EventID = dbo.Attendee.EventID 
  JOIN dbo.Account ON dbo.Booking.UserID = dbo.Account.UserID
 WHERE (dbo.Booking.EventID = 15)
```

Output:

[image: output of the above query]

The issue with the generated table is the column product purchased and driver name is populated with text for every row which in this case it should be populated for only the rows which has `Drivername` and product purchased. There is only one row in the attendee table which has `drivername`, product purchase fields populated for username mark, while all the other rows has null value for both the `drivername` and products.

Comment: What is the relationship between Booking and Attendee?  Is it 1 to 1 or 1 to many?

Comment: Please show actual sample data in tabular format instead of describing the data as a word problem. Also it is often useful to mention which version of SQL Server you are using, as query solutions can vary when newer language features are appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need driver name, the following could help:

```
SELECT
    B.EventId,
    B.Cost,
    B.StatusID,
    A.FirstName,
    SUM(AT.HelmetsPurchased) AS ProductsPurchased,
    SUM(AT.GaragesPurchased) AS GaragesPurchased
FROM
    dbo.Booking B
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Account A ON B.UserID = A.UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Attendee AT ON B.EventID = AT.EventID 
WHERE (dbo.Booking.EventID = 15)
GROUP BY B.EventId, B.Cost, B.StatusId, A.FirstName
```

Comment: The result i m getting is 15 rows , although the total rows are 9 which have eventId = 15

Comment: I guess the issue is as one client with same UserID has 6,7 entries in the attendee table with separate ID's, for instance one client has bought 1 ticket with no products for some event , and the same client next time has bought 2 tickets with some products for the same event.

Comment: @Mr A: It sounds like you have a 1 to many relationship here.  The question is where.  Are there multiple Accounts per booking or multiple Attendees per booking or both?  I'd suggest you provide a small sample of the data from each of the tables involved in your question.

Comment: @Mr A: in that case, 15 records is accurate given your data.  You might want to state exactly what it is you are trying to do if you only want 9 records.

Comment: yeh but the total booking for eventId=15 is 9 , therefore it shud show only 9 rows, also why its mixing the drivername and products purchased as only 2 rows have got the values for those columns rest have got null so it out of 9 rows 7 rows should have null values for drivername and products

Comment: Its showing 7 rows now but still the ProductsPurchased and Garages Purchased are filled with some unrelaistic numbers

Comment: @ChrisLively let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1156/discussion-between-muhammad-awais-and-chris-lively)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of an `INNER JOIN` on the table Attendee you should do a `LEFT JOIN`.  This will include rows where these two columns are null as well.

```
   SELECT b.Cost, 
          b.StatusID, 
          ac.FirstName, 
          at.HelmetsPurchased AS ProductsPurchased, 
          at.GaragesPurchased, 
          at.SecondDriver AS [Driver Name]
     FROM dbo.Booking b
LEFT JOIN dbo.Attendee at ON b.EventID = at.EventID 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Account ac ON b.UserID = ac.UserID
    WHERE b.EventID = 15
```

Comment: tried    dbo.Booking LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Attendee ON dbo.Booking.EventID = dbo.Attendee.EventID INNER JOIN
 which gives same results

Comment: @Mr A do you have something in your `WHERE` clause that you didn't include in your question that references Attendee? Or an additional table in the `FROM`

Comment: The result i m getting using the above query is 15 rows , although the total rows are 9 which have eventId = 15

Comment: I guess the issue is as one client with same UserID has 6,7 entries in the attendee table with separate ID's, for instance one client has bought 1 ticket with no products for some event , and the same client next time has bought 2 tickets with some products for the same event.